# Why Dumbledore didn't keep Tom's diary to study it?

Tags: harry-potter

The remains of the defeated Horcrux was in Dumbledore's possession after Harry's adventure in the Chamber of Secrets,  but it was returned to Lucius Malfoy. Why?

Comment: Lucius Malfoy didn't show up 5 minutes after the Horcrux was destroyed. Dumbledore probably had plenty of time to examine it and realize the extent of the damage done by the Basilisk rendered it completely useless. So he let Harry save Dobby with it.

Comment: @amflare sure, but more time, more tests... so many missed possibilities... For example freeing Dobby but asking him not to reveal it to Lucius. I wonder, could've dobby faked it? After all Lucy had no idea till dobby told him.

Comment: @Lt.Ortega - that has absolutely nothing to do with the diary

Answer (score 1):

**There was nothing left to study.**

We see other Horcruxes in later books, and in every case, after the Horcrux has been destroyed (or, you could say, the Magic has been removed), the object was simply an object, a worthless trinket. Dumbledore would have wanted to study the Dark Magic that Tom Riddle had used, but it no longer existed in the diary. Similarly, there was no magic left in the ring that cursed Dumbledore's hand, or in the locket, after the Horcrux part had been destroyed.